# How to save large circular Javascript object?

Tags: javascript, json, object

I have a very very large JavaScript object which has a lot of circular references in it. It contains geometry and some mathematical data. Problem is, that I want to save that object to file or database, or anything, so that I can use it later in my application.

I've tried with JSON.Stringify, but of course it doesn't work because of circular references. I've also tried cycle.js without luck.

What is the standard practice to save big JS objects ?

Comment: I don't know that there is any sort of "standard practice". You could probably serialize it with YAML, as it has support for circular references (I think).

Comment: google `circular json`, if this helps you accept my answer please.